# Kubernetes Ingress Nginx Controller 404 Not Found

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I am trying to use Kubernetes Ingress Nginx Controller and when I run skaffold run and go to host through my browser, the browser page displays 404 Not Found nginx. I tried running my docker image in a docker container and that works fine so I don't think there is anything run with my Dockerfile. (I am just trying to run a blank React App)

Here is my code for /infra/k8s/ingress-srv.yaml:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-srv
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: 'true'
spec:
  rules:
    - host: posts.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /?(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: client-srv
              servicePort: 3000
```

And here is my code for /infra/k8s/client-depl.yaml (I'm putting client service in the same file):

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: client-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: client
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: client
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: client
          image: aidenhsy/client
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: client-srv
spec:
  selector:
    app: client
  ports:
    - name: client
      protocol: TCP
      port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000
```

And finally here is my skaffold.yaml in the root folder:

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v2alpha3
kind: Config
deploy:
  kubectl:
    manifests:
      - ./infra/k8s/*
build:
  local:
    push: false
  artifacts:
    - image: aidenhsy/client
      context: client
      docker:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      sync:
        manual:
          - src: 'src/**/*.js'
            dest: .
```

Here is a screenshot of an image of the webpage when I try to load it [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENLWU.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

AY.

Comment: Are you trying to access it via http or https as ingress via https needs to set `tls` in the rule object too?
Also if you don't need to use regex, just set the path to `path: /` or even don't set it

Comment: I am trying to access it with https on google chrome and I'm using "thisisunsafe" to override the warning, I am new to this and I'm just trying to get this to work.

Comment: Have you looked at the logs in the nginx controller? That logs out when it tries to resolve the endpoints and should show you which services it's trying to hit. You can use kubectl to get the name of the nginx controller instance running and then get the log for it

Comment: Just checking as well, are the pods up and ready? You can test exactly what the service is looking for with `kubectl get pod --selector=app=client --namespace <your namespace`